# How can I ensure more than one specific cron job exist using host_vars?

Tags: loops, cron, ansible

I want to write an ansible playbook (I am pretty new to ansible - so be kind with me) that checks if various cronjobs exist in the user crontab. The jobs should just execute various scripts. The jobs are the same for all hosts except for the script name. A line in the crontab looks like this:

```
30 5 * * * /path/to/script/monitoringScript_serviceX > /path/to/script/monitoringScript_serviceX.out 2>&1
```

Depending on which host I am on there are different services defined, resulting in different script names. I defined the services as a YAML list in host_vars in one file per host (inventory/host_vars/host1/services)

One services file looks something like this:

```
services:
    - service1
    - service2
```

Some of the hosts only have one defined service.

My playbook looks like this:

```
  - hosts: hostgroupX
    gather_facts: False
    tasks:
      - name: Ensure monitoring cron jobs are present
        cron:
            name: "check: monitoring data jobs"
            hour: "5"
            minute: "30"
            user: "user"
            job: "/path/to/script/monitoringScript_{{ item }} > /path/to/script/monitoringScript_{{ item }}.out 2>&1"
        loop: "{{ services }}"
```

If I let the play run on one host on which only one service is defined in the file everything is working well.

But if there is more than one service defined only the last one in the list is written in the crontab. The result with the example services file from above would look like this:

```
#Ansible: check: monitoring data jobs 
30 5 * * * /path/to/script/monitoringScript_service2 > /path/to/script/monitoringScript_service2.out 2>&1
```

even though I want it to look like this:

```
#Ansible: check: monitoring data jobs 
30 5 * * * /path/to/script/monitoringScript_service1 > /path/to/script/monitoringScript_service1.out 2>&1
30 5 * * * /path/to/script/monitoringScript_service2 > /path/to/script/monitoringScript_service2.out 2>&1
```

I would appreciate any ideas how to achieve this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible uses the name of your cron job as a unique identifier; it will remove any matching jobs before adding the new one. This is to prevent multiple runs of ansible from appending duplicate cron jobs every time you run.

The solution is to include the service name in the cron job name, like this:

```
- name: Ensure monitoring cron jobs are present
  cron:
      name: "check: monitoring data for service {{ item }}"
      hour: "5"
      minute: "30"
      user: "user"
      job: "/path/to/script/monitoringScript_{{ item }} > /path/to/script/monitoringScript_{{ item }}.out 2>&1"
  loop: "{{ services }}"
```

This would get you cron entries that look something like:

```
#Ansible: check: monitoring data for service service1
30 5 * * * /path/to/script/monitoringScript_service1 ...
#Ansible: check: monitoring data for service service2
30 5 * * * /path/to/script/monitoringScript_service2 ...
#Ansible: check: monitoring data for service service3
30 5 * * * /path/to/script/monitoringScript_service3 ...
```

Comment: What about adding the cronjobs to the same cron_file on /etc/cron.d ? I have a similar structure and all cronjobs get added correctly to the user's crontab, but if I add cron_file to the cron definition with the same file name for all jobs only the last one is added. The idea for me is to have a cronjobs file per application type (ie, wordpress, octobercms, etc) instead of a unique user crontab with all applications jobs.

Comment: @Juancho you should probably post a  new question, and include a playbook that reproduces the problem.